# Can't add some URLs to Google Bookmark

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

For some unknown and strange reason, I can't add

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox
```

into Google Bookmark.  I use the Google Chrome in OSX and Google Bookmark's "bookmarklet."  I can successfully add other URLs as bookmark though.

Comment: Have you tried updating the bookmarklet?

Comment: Tried before posting; does not help.

Comment: Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_paradox. Maybe there's a bug with URL encoded strings in the OS X build of Chrome.

Comment: It does not help.

Comment: So that's two URLs you can't bookmark. Are those the only two? I'd try another one with an apostrophe in it.

Comment: I can bookmark http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool's_Gold_(2008_film)

Comment: These all work on Windows, so I'm going to add an OS X tag. By the way, what actually happens? Do you even get the new window to confirm the bookmark?